# Show that $1/f$ is bounded if $X$ is compact and let $f:X \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is compact and let $f:X \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be continuous. Show that $1/f$ is bounded. Does this hold when $X$ is not compact?

Comment: Have a look at $f(x)=x$ on $x\in (0,\infty)$..

Comment: Actually citing examples will not solve the problem for me. I require this proof in generality.

Comment: @PriyadarshiMukherjee Thomas was answering your second question since their $f: (0, \infty) \to  (0, \infty)$ is defined on $X$ which is not compact. There a counterexample would certainly suffice,

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:X \to (0,+\infty)$ be a continuous function with $X \subseteq  \mathbb{R}$ compact. Since the image of a compact set via a continuous function is compact, $f(X)$ is compact, and because this is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it is bounded. Now, $\frac{1}{f} \leq \frac{1}{\min f(X)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous, $\frac1f$ is continuous too and, since $X$ is compact, its image by $\frac1f$ is compact and therefore bounded.

If $X$ is not compact, then this may not be true. For instance, take $X=(0,+\infty)$ and $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

The continuous image of a compact space is compact, and compact spaces are closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$.

This means that $f(X) \subset [a,b]$ for some $0<a<b$, and therefore $1/f$ is bounded.

This does not hold if $X$ is not compact (consider $X = ]0;1]$ with $f(x)=x$).

Answer (score 0):

As $f$ is a continuous function on a compact space, it achieves its infimum on that space $X$.  Since $f$ cannot take the value 0, the minimum of $f$ on X is some $\delta > 0$. Since $ \forall x \in X, f(x) > \delta $ we have that $\frac{1}{f} < \frac{1}{\delta}$ everywhere on X.

It doesn't work without compactness as can be seen from $f:(0,1) \longrightarrow (0,\infty)$ given by $f(x)=x$